# What actions can cause an HTML FORM element to submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I am aware of the Enter key, clicking the submit button and calling form.submit() to submit the form element of an HTML page.

Are there more actions that will cause a submit?

Comment: By "submit button" you're counting both `<input type="submit" />` and `<input type="image" />`, correct?

Comment: clicking `<button>` elements inside a form tends to do a submit as well.

Comment: @MarcB as a rule that is not generaly the case

Comment: @Wiseguy Yes, type="image" would be counted.

Comment: @MarcB Tend to, or can?  It seems they default to type="button".

Comment: `<form method="get"><input type="hidden" name="hi" value="there"><button>click me</button></form>`. clicking that button will submit the form.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, you are correct.  It seems that only IE (in some versions) defaults to type="button"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read about [form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#implicit-submission) in the HTML5 spec.

Importantly note:

> User agents may establish a button in each form as being the form's default button.

and

> ...[the form] is submitted from an element submitter (typically a button), optionally with a "submitted from `submit()` method flag" attached

Comment: Link has changed. Please see [this link](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#forms-form-submission).

Comment: @DustinCleveland, thank you for catching that. I've updated the link to point to the spec as it was when I wrote this answer. Of course, newer specs will have updated language, but generally speaking will probably remain consistent around how implicit submission works.

Answer (score 1):

another way to force a `click` on say a button is to invoke its click which would cause the form to submit, if a submit exists.

`force click` to submit form

```
<input type="button"  value="ddddd" onclick="document.oform.osubmit.click();" />
<input type="submit" name="osubmit" value="Send" />
```